# Assign tags to chat rooms

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat

Is (or would) it be possible to assign SO tags to chat rooms in order to indicate what is the focus of particular room?

Comment: Is there any reason that this "focus" indication can't be accomplished with the room title and description?

Comment: What if the room is not specialized only in one tag but let's say a group of tags. For example [Web developers lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/575/web-developers-lounge) which can focus on many tags. Also the chat room can be linked directly to tags on SO in some way.

Comment: @yojimbo If you specialize in a whole lot more than you can specify in the description, general or itemized, then wouldn't tags just limit your focus?

Comment: @Grace: Sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean by "limit your focus". You mean that if there are no tags which can specify room purpose then it will limit it's focus?

Comment: I'm tagging **Let's get philosophical** [philosophy], [dinosaurs], [jeff-atwood], [bees] and [lasers].

Comment: @yojimbo For example, if your subject matter is just "C++", you can just use one word to describe it. Comparatively, the Web developer's lounge has a description of "A place to talk about HTML, CSS, JavaScript, or anything else related to Web Development." If you associate tags to this, then you're suggesting that the scope is limited to only what you can find tags for. This is not always going to be the case, especially for much wider reaching topics. The current description gives examples of what's allowed without limiting the scope to just those languages.

Comment: @Grace: I see, well you can still have the choice to include relevant tags, but it doesn't necessarily  mean that you can't talk out of scope. I thought about it more like a inter connection between SO and chat functionality so that rooms can obtain more users for example.

Comment: @Grace: yes, you will never the chatroom for R language: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131041/so-chatroom-filter-does-not-work-on-words-tags-and-hence-the-chatroom-for-r-can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm completely in favor of this proposal, if only to help alleviate the problem which is worse than duplicate questions: duplicate chat rooms. It would be one thing if there were enough traffic to maintain [eight rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/632173#632173), but there isn't. I think that a viable solution to the problem of duplicate Android chat rooms.

Also on the topic of duplicate chat rooms, perhaps the mods should (or should have, initially?) open(ed) a chat room per language. I think that I would be sufficient to have one for C, one for C++, one for Java, .NET, one for each of the major mobile platforms and one for the "other" languages.

Another option is to rais the minimum rep required to open a chat room on SO. Other sites are perhaps less likely to run into duplicates, but SO chat room opening "powers" have obviously been abused.

So... I agree with this proposal, along with some of my other suggestions. Lets make chat more active by keeping dupe rooms from opening and spreading conversation too thin.

**Just to clarify:**

I suggest this for StackOverflow, but creating a set of rooms on another stackexchange site may well be a terrible idea. I refer specifically to StackOverflow where this issue needs to be addressed.

Comment: I disagree on opening one chat room per language, what would they do for sites with less traffic or less discernible topics, like EL&U, or what rooms would they open on a niche site like http://dba.stackexchange.edu?

Comment: I am speaking specifically about StackOverflow, where the subject matter provides a relatively unique set of chat room topics. The current system is fine for most StackExchange sites. SO seems to present a unique problem

Comment: Which is primarily only due to volume. What happens when the rest of the network's sites are this popular (we can hope)

Comment: Well, depends on the site. English has some cut and dry topics too, like usage, grammar, etymology, spelling etc.