# Is it okay to create solicitous chatroom on the site?

Tags: discussion, chat

There is a particular user who has created a particular chatroom where his intentions are very clear. He wants to attract attention of girls to the room and wants to chat with them. (Not sure if he will succeed but whatever.) While, I personally do not have any problem with it, I am wondering whether it is in good policies of the site to allow such chatrooms to exist for a long time. It might be difficult to auto-detect such chatrooms, but would the moderators be sympathetic if someone reports such chatrooms?

P.S. I am perfectly fine if site policy allows such chatrooms to exist, I just want to get it confirmed.

Comment: I think that this user has deep problems with perception of reality in first line :)

Comment: @ŁukaszLech Which user? Me?

Comment: This who wants to use SO chat as dating portal. Hmmm... maybe I should use word 'that' (I have problems with those 2)

Comment: @Lukasz In the spirit of being helpful, I actually think neither really work. While 'that' is more useful here, I would personally opt for "The user who," as it's generally clearer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, **this is not appropriate**. See [Definitive rules on chat rooms with non-technical discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139362/definitive-rules-on-chat-rooms-with-non-technical-discussion) (The policy is for chat.SO, but it extends to chat.SE as well)

Under "Signs of inappropriate rooms", here are the points such a chat room violates

> - The room's given topic (and thus its definition) already hints at the fact that people explicitly not want to talk about stuff that would be considered [site]-related.

Nope. Dating/attracting girls has nothing to do with any chat parent site.

> - The room generates conversation in a tone that cannot by any stretch of imagination be considered "professional". This may e.g. be A/S/L types of conversation, bullying, back-and-forth accusations, etc.

This seems to be *exactly* an A/S/L room.

> - The real-world equivalent of the room would be people waiting at a bus stop

Sounds about right.

Please let us know which room it is so that it can be dealt with (flag it or link to it in your post).

Comment: I have already done so. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik: is it on chat.SO? there's a high chance the flag won't be seen

Comment: Its not on chat.SE and I checked the room again, and it was deleted. So, it was seen.

Comment: Sorry,  I meant, it is on chat.SE and not on chat.SO

Comment: @JayeshBadwaik: OK, I see which room you're talking about. I'll keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 12):

It's fine to use chat to talk to specific people.

It's not cool to use chat to stalk and/or harass people online. If you see things the wrong side of creepy please flag the user (via a post from them on the main site) and explain. We'll look into it and take appropriate actions.