# Create chat room without specific topic

Tags: discussion, chat

I am thinking of creating a chat room  on Stack Overflow with my name and description:

> For any issues you need to discuss with me from the Stack Overflow - constructive criticism only

As I make mistakes and sometimes these can lead to discussions off topic from the original question, is this an appropriate chat room to have linked to my Stack Overflow profile?

Another thing: would such a chat room be more appropriate for the meta or the main site?
Or do I keep coming here and using this site?

Comment: Tavern on the Meta?

Comment: Tavern? sorry I don't understand.. if you mean on SO or meta then yes, that should be part of my questions, which is more appropriate for a chat room like that

Comment: There's a chat room called "tavern on the meta" here.

Comment: oh sorry, is that a suitable place for this? I just thought if someone wanted to address something with me directly.. I don't want to put up my email address, as ANYONE could use it

Comment: If someone wants to address you directly, that's what comments are for. For general off topic discussion, use tavern on the meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am thinking of creating a chat room

Yes, you may create one, but first read the [chat room rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139382/173001).

> Is this an appropriate chat room to have linked to my Stack Overflow profile?

Yes you can put chat room's link into your "about me" section.

> Would such a chat room be more appropriate for the meta or the main site?

Stack Overflow is for programming related Question & Answers while Meta Stack Overflow is for queries, feature requests, bug reporting, etc. related to Stack Exchange sites. So I think you should not create such a chat room on meta as it has no meaning here.

> Or do I keep coming here and using this forum?

You can visit meta if you have a query, feature request, bug report, answer to other's question, etc.

But my personal advice would be to use an existing chat room dedicated to your technology, it is nice idea.