# Chat Is Extremely Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, chat, off-topic

Recently, I was on the bit-coin chat. I was trying to find info on mining algorithms. I was surprised at the amount of crap in there. People were on there talking about weed and such things that did not have much to do with the topic. Is this allowed? I mean, we cant do this kind of stuff on stack?

Comment: Related: [Definitive rules on chat rooms with non-technical discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139362/162704). Also, perhaps this is a bit more appropriate for Meta.Bitcoin?

Comment: "*People were on there talking about[...]things that did not have much to do with the topic.*" **So what?**

Comment: Which room is this exactly? The first mention of *weed* on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/bitcoin-lounge is from Feb 25th: *interested in joining on weeding out bad tags.*

Answer (score 4):

[What can we talk about in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#about)--- ([From FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq))

> This site is an extension of Stack Overflow, so discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.

So, yes chat is designed to be an "extension", meaning another place that we can go to get additional help and ask questions which are off-topic for the main site. But this doesn't mean we have to keep the talk **strictly** to that.

Chat is also a place for us to discuss other things with, possibly, like-minded people. I am a  regular in [Android room 15](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) and I love it because of being able to discuss things we find humorous, science, math, our kids, or whatever.

With that said, we do discuss a lot of Android related things and are not just there to goof off.

### However

Talking about things such as drugs or doing other inappropriate things of that nature should be avoided and if you find it offensive then you can flag those posts. But if the things they are discussing aren't really offensive and they do still allow bitcoin discussions then I don't see a problem with it. Although, the topics should try to stay somewhat professional. Otherwise, you may suggest they rename the room to "Drug Haven" or some such name.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#about) says:

> This site is an extension of The Stack Exchange Network, so discussion should **more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at The Stack Exchange Network** — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.

So in short: no, that is not a topic that should be on chat.