# Can I create a casual chat room for my colleagues?

Tags: discussion, chat

I like the chat room features provided here on SE. I am planning to create a public chat room (*possibly, with my company name*) here where my colleagues and I can hangout. The reason of this chat room would be to have some fun while working in office. The fun can be related to funny stuff (*mostly*) or technical problems posted by a colleague.

I am somewhat confused whether the room I created will be allowed to exist or not as it is not completely related to technical stuff.

I am sure this room will not come under [inappropriate room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139382/196352).

Comment: Check out slack.com - they have a free tier. With a few exceptions (the most notable being threaded replies) it does pretty much everything SE chat does.

Comment: @Iain thanks.. btw I know some chat rooms but they are not as pretty as SE chat room. Anyway, my alternate one would be [this](https://jabbr.net) if I fail here.

Comment: Side note, you might like [Miaou](http://dystroy.org/miaou/)

Answer (score 8):

No, creating a chat room with your company's name for your colleagues sounds like a bad idea, as well as a bit promotional.

From [the FAQ of MSE chat:](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#about)

> This site is an extension of Meta Stack Exchange, so **discussion should
> more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Meta Stack
> Exchange** — but in an interactive, less strictly Q&A focused way. Do
> have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of
> your fellow community members.

(emphasis mine)

#### Potential for abuse:

There may also be involuntary engagement in voting patterns in future, if such rooms are allowed. When any post comes to the attention via a chat room, users tend to vote on it individually as per their own choice, but this results in concentrated voting. If all the users are from same company and related to similar technologies, the posts which you vote on may tend to become concentrated and lead to voting patterns. I am sure this isn't you intention, but this seems like a potential for abuse.

Comment: I agree I should not create a chat as I mentioned above. but still just for clarification: what if I create on SO (_just like [javascript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-too-many-cooks) with no company name_) and also I am sure my colleagues are not interested in rep points?

Comment: @Mr_Green [The real-world equivalent of the room would be people waiting at a bus stop.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139382/245167)