# How do chat room tags work?

Tags: support, tags, chat

I can't seem to find any documentation on the mechanics of tagging a chat room.

- What is the benefit of tagging a room? Based on how they're used in the Teachers' Lounge, I used to think it dictated what questions were fed into the room, but that's based on the room's feeds, not its tags. So what purpose does it have?
- Any tag you specify shows up underneath the chat room name, and they link to the list of questions in that tag on the main site: is there a way to specify meta discussion site tags? `meta-tag:foo` doesn't seem to work, nor does `foo` (where `foo` is a meta-tag).

Comment: Related meta where the feature was originally requested: [Assign tags to chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86290/assign-tags-to-chat-rooms)

Answer (score 5):

> - What is the benefit of tagging a room? Based on how they're used in the Teachers' Lounge, I used to think it dictated what questions were fed into the room, but that's based on the room's feeds, not its tags. So what purpose does it have?

Certain tags may cause a link to the room to show up underneath various areas of the main site with that tag, for example at its main page `/tags/foo`, its wiki, and in questions that are tagged `foo`. I guess that's one benefit.

Comment: Is this the only thing that they are used for?  I can't find any other documentation either.